# How to configure multi-hop in wireless ad-hoc network?

Tags: wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I have a wireless ad-hoc network with 3 machines A,B and C. They are all in the 192.168.160.x subnet and have a corresponding subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 . A and B can ping each other, A and C can ping each other but B and C cannot ping each other (they are far off). Using wireshark(at A), I determined that when I request B to ping C, it sends out an ARP request with C's IP. C can't hear B, so B does not get a reply. B therefore shows Destination host unreachable. But should not there be some way that the A can forward B's request to C? Are standard wireless ad-hoc networks limited to single-hop?

I'm using ubuntu jaunty on all machines, with atheros cards using the madwifi driver.

Comment: So I just realized that ad-hoc can mean two things - Mobile Ad-Hoc Networks(MANET), which are multi-hop, and ad-hoc in 802.11 spec, which is single-hop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to be running host A in [*hostap* mode](http://blog.robin.smidsrod.no/2008/08/08/how_to_setup_an_atheros_based_access_poi) and switching from Ad-Hoc to Infrastructure mode.  That way traffic that wants to go from B to C should go via A.